# Replace value in multiple columns of dataframe based on ID

Tags: r

I have a dataframe similar to the below

| ID | FirstName | LastName | Orders | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | 3 | 30 |
| 2 | John | Smith | 7 | 8 |
| 3 | John | Smith | 9 | 317 |
| 4 | John | Smith | 12 | 20 |

I need to do the equivalent of a find and replace based on a number of IDs where if a match is found within the list, 'FirstName', 'LastName' and 'Age' are changed to value 'Redacted'. So I can start with setting up IDList like below with the necessary IDs:

```
IDList <- c(1,3,74,312)
```

But can anyone please advise how to code in order that final table would look like this:

| ID | FirstName | LastName | Orders | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Redacted | Redacted | 3 | Redacted |
| 2 | John | Smith | 7 | 8 |
| 3 | Redacted | Redacted | 9 | Redacted |
| 4 | John | Smith | 12 | 20 |

Thank you.

Comment: Do be careful putting strings in your numeric columns--the whole column will no longer be numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may make a single assignment here:

```r
cols <- c("FirstName", "LastName", "Age")
df[df$ID %in% IDList, cols] <- "Redacted"
df

  ID FirstName LastName Orders      Age
1  1  Redacted Redacted      3 Redacted
2  2      John    Smith      7        8
3  3  Redacted Redacted      9 Redacted
4  4      John    Smith     12       20
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1:4), FirstName=rep("John", 4),
                 LastName=rep("Smith", 4), Orders=c(3,7,9,12), 
                 Age=c(30,8,317,20), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
IDList <- c(1,3,74,312)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(FirstName, LastName, Age), ~ifelse(ID %in% IDList, "Redacted", .)))
```

```
  ID FirstName LastName Orders      Age
1  1  Redacted Redacted      3 Redacted
2  2      John    Smith      7        8
3  3  Redacted Redacted      9 Redacted
4  4      John    Smith     12       20
```

Comment: How could you adjust this if you wanted to pass a different value to each column instead of just "Redacted" from another column?

Comment: instead of "Redacted" just use the name of the column you want to get the values of. Here is an example: `mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(c(am, mpg), ~ifelse(am==1, gear, .)))`

Answer (score 0):

Using simple `base` R

```
df$Age = ifelse(df$ID %in% IDList, 'Redacted', df$Age)

  ID FirstName LastName Orders      Age
1  1      John    Smith      3 Redacted
2  2      John    Smith      7        8
3  3      John    Smith      9 Redacted
4  4      John    Smith     12       20
```